# Opencart Kingstore lite href variable undefined

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using OpenCart 2.2.0 with Kingstore Lite theme

At the order history when i try to view the details of one order i do get the error message:

Notice
:Undefined index: href in catalog/view/theme/kingstorepro/template/account/order_list.tpl on line 
29

This is the line:

```
<td class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $order['href']; ?>"
```

and the route is : index.php?route=account/order

How can i fix ? is at the controller or at the model ? how can i find and fix?

Comment: I think, You need to contact to it theme author.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code instead of above -

```
<td class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $order['view']; ?>"
```

Hope this will help you.